Python Daemon Threading: How do I trigger the flag from my thread to exit the main thread?
I am using Python Threading where the attribute Daemon is set to true. I want to trigger the flag in my thread and if that thread is triggered, I want to exit the program. In my main loop I am getting the inpput
import threading
import time
import sys

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.done = False
        self.inp = ''
        
    def worker(self):
        count = 0
        while True:
            if self.inp == 'start':
                print(f"Hello from Worker {count}")
                count += 1
                time.sleep(1)
                if count == 3:
                    self.done = True
                    return
                
    def start(self):
        while not self.done:
            self.inp = input('Enter input: ')
            print(self.done)
            time.sleep(1)
        
        print("Main Thread ending")
        sys.exit()

test = Test()
# Create a thread
thread = threading.Thread(target=test.worker)
# Set the thread as a daemon thread
thread.daemon = True
# Start the thread
thread.start()
test.start()

# Main thread sleeps for 5 seconds
time.sleep(5)


The main thread does not exit when I am getting the keyboard input, if I delete that code snippet, it exists gracefully.

You say, "The main thread does not exit when I am getting the keyboard input, if I delete that code snippet, it exists gracefully." What code snippet? The call to input('Enter input: ')? The daemon thread will permanently loop until start is entered by the user, so you need this in your main thread, but not necessarily in a loop.
First of all, the statement time.sleep(5) (your final line of code) will never be executed because it is preceded by the statement test.start() and this later call to method start never returns because it is an infinite loop that only terminates when sys.exit() is executed and that causes the main thread and any daemon threads created to terminate.
Second, the daemon thread you create is in an infinite loop that repeatedly tests the condition self.inp == 'start' before it does anything. Therefore, the first thing that must be typed in by the user is start. In the meanwhile the code is needlessly burning up CPU cycles executing repeatedly the test if self.inp == 'start:'.
Then after start has been entered the daemon thread essentially loops a few times before it sets self.done = True. It then issues a return from the loop terminating the daemon thread. There is no need for this to be a daemon thread, which is normally used for threads that do not terminate by themselves but you want to have them terminated automatically when the main thread terminates. But even though the thread has set self.done to True, the main thread is hanging on the call to input('Enter input: ') and will not check the self.done flag until the user types in more input. I would suggest calling input repeatedly only until start has been entered and then loop until the child thread signals it to stop. I would suggest that you use threading.Event instances for signaling between threads in the following manner (please read the comments):
import threading
import time

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.begin = threading.Event()
        self.done = threading.Event()

    def worker(self):
        # Wait for main thread to tell us to begin (this does not
        # burn up any wasteful CPU cycles):
        self.begin.wait()

        for count in range(1, 4):
            print(f"Hello from Worker {count}")
            # Lets make this 2 seconds for variety:
            time.sleep(2)

        # Now we will terminate, but first tell the main
        # thread to stop:
        self.done.set()
        print('Child thread ending')

    def start(self):
        while True:
            inp = input('Enter start to get things running: ')
            if inp == 'start':
                # tell child thread to begin:
                self.begin.set()
                break

        while True:
            # Wait for the done event to be set or for 1 second
            # if the event has not been set within that period of time:
            if self.done.wait(1.0):  # The event has been set
                print('The done event has been set and the main thread is ending.')
                return
            print('The done event has not been set.')


test = Test()

# Create a thread (it does not need to be a daemon thread):
thread = threading.Thread(target=test.worker)
thread.start()

test.start()

# When we return to here the child thread has either
# terminated or is in the process of terminating.
# If we want to explicitly wait until it has terminated before
# preceeding, we can call thread.join(). Since there is nothing
# further for this script to do, there is no need to call
# thread.join() and the program will terminate as soon as the
# child thread has completed its termination, which should be immediately
# if it hasn't already terminated.

Prints:
Enter start to get things running: start
Hello from Worker 1
The done event has not been set.
Hello from Worker 2
The done event has not been set.
The done event has not been set.
Hello from Worker 3
The done event has not been set.
The done event has not been set.
Child thread ending
The done event has been set and the main thread is ending.

